# Is it common for noun phrases and clauses to act as parallelism?

Tags: grammar

> It is de rigueur to follow **that description with an immediate
> disclaimer**, in which both computer scientists and neuroscientists jump
> in nervously to point out that the analogy is very rough, **that anns
> are mere cartoons of real brains (if even that)** and **that they fail to
> capture the complexity of the biological organ**.

Parallelism——**that description with an immediate disclaimer,that anns are mere cartoons of real brains (if even that),that they fail to capture the complexity of the biological organ.** ——should have the same structure.Is it true,here?

Comment: *... both computer scientists and neuroscientists jump in nervously to point out that the analogy is very rough, [**both computer scientists and neuroscientists jump in nervously to point out**] that anns are mere cartoons of real brains (if even that), and [**both computer scientists and neuroscientists jump in nervously to point out**] that they fail to capture the complexity of the biological organ.* The highlighted elements are "predictably repeated", so they can just be deleted. What's the problem? The repeated part is the subject+verb, with different complements.

Comment: @FumbleFingers,"that description with an immediate disclaimer" is not the subject+verb.

Comment: *It is de rigueur to follow that description with an immediate disclaimer. **The disclaimer is one** in which both computer scientists and neuroscientists...*

Comment: The first "that" phrase is entirely different grammar from the other two. There's no connection whatsoever between them